# A row in a postgresql table doesn't show up when running specific queries

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I'm running a private gitlab community edition server which is using [sameersbn/postgresql:9.5-4](https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/postgresql/) as its database.

There's a weird phenomenon inside the database:

When I run the following queries, I can find a row whose `id` is `144` from the returned data.

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id > 143 ORDER BY id;
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id < 145 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But I can't find a row whose `id` is `144` using the following queries.

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id = 144;
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id > 143 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1; 
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id < 145 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; 
SELECT id FROM projects ORDER by id;
```

This is so strange. It makes me able to see the project in gitlab. But when I click on the project, I see 404 `The page could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.` error.

Anyone knows what might cause this problem?

The version of my postgresql is `PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit`.

Comment: Does `reindex projects;`  fix this? What is your exact Postgres version? (`select version();` will show you)

Comment: I'm afraid that `reindex projects;` will make the gitlab unavailable. It's a service that is used by all the developers in my company. Let me check if I can create a backup before running this command.

Comment: Unless you have millions of rows that will only take a few seconds. You could start with just reindexing the index on the column `id`.

Comment: `REINDEX TABLE projects;` solves my problem.

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version?

Comment: It's `PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit`. I added the version at the end of my question.

Comment: You should really [upgrade](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.5.5&to=9.5.16&keywords=) to the latest 9.5. bugfix release. There were several index related bugfixes in the 2 years of updates you are missing which might have prevented this problem to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will upgrade the version of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *a_horse_with_no_name*'s comment. I use `REINDEX TABLE projects;` to solve my problem.